# Функция со switch с переменным количеством case

Tags: c++, c

Допустим, у меня есть несколько таких блоков:

```
    // Ввод символа
    do switch (_getch()) {
    // Делать одно
    case '1': dosmth1();
        break;
    // Делать второе
    case '2': dosmth2();
        break;
    // Делать третье
    case '3': dosmth3();
        break;
    // Выйти
    case '0': dosmth0();
        return 0;
    } while (true);
```

Но, ввиду частого создания оных, возникает вопрос:

Как организовать такую функцию `menu()`, которая создавала бы n-ное количество `case`, соответствующих n-ному количеству параметров (указателей на функции)?

---

Вызов такой функции по принципу `stdarg`:

```
menu(4, dosmth1, dosmth2, dosmth3, dosmth0);
```

Comment: Так и заведите массив указателей на функции. А если case не по порядку, то map с указателями. Сами же решение уже придумали.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если сигнатуры вызываемых функций одинаковы, то самый простой способ - использовать контейнер типа `std::map`, `std::unordered_map`. Ключом будет выступать char или int, а в качестве типа значения использоваться указатель на функцию. Например:

```
std::map<int, void(*)()> action;
```

Когда контейнер заполнен использование может быть сокращено до вида:

```
action[_getch()]();
```

Понятно, что в общем случае могут потребоваться дополнительные проверки на существование элемента, т.к. по умолчанию оператор `[]` приводит к созданию элемента, если его не было.

Answer (score 3):

Несмотря на то что ответ уже принят, предложу вариант решения с помощью шаблонов с переменным числом аргументов (работает начиная с C++11):

```
typedef void(*ActionFunction)();
bool _menu(int condition, int action_counter, ActionFunction action)
{
    if (action_counter == condition) {
        action();
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
template<typename... Args>
bool _menu(int condition, int action_counter, ActionFunction action, Args... args)
{
    if (action_counter == condition) {
        action();
        return true;
    }
    return _menu(condition, ++action_counter, args...);
}
template<typename... Args>
bool menu(int condition, ActionFunction action, Args... args)
{
    return _menu(condition, 0, action, args...);
}
```

Функция `menu` принимает номер функции, которую надо выполнить (действия нумеруются с нуля), и дальше любое количество указателей на функции. Если функции будут иметь разную сигнатуру, то надо просто дополнительно определить пару функций `_menu` (шаблонную и обычную) с нужным типом аргумента в третьей позиции. Также функция `menu` возвращает `true`, если значение было найдено, и `false`, если нет.

Пример (функции имеют сигнатуру `void(*)()`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print0() { printf("0\n"); }
void print1() { printf("1\n"); }
void print2() { printf("2\n"); }
void print3() { printf("3\n"); }

typedef void(*ActionFunction)();

bool _menu(int condition, int action_counter, ActionFunction action)
{
    if (action_counter == condition) {
        action();
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
template<typename... Args>
bool _menu(int condition, int action_counter, ActionFunction action, Args... args)
{
    if (action_counter == condition) {
        action();
        return true;
    }
    return _menu(condition, ++action_counter, args...);
}
template<typename... Args>
bool menu(int condition, ActionFunction action, Args... args)
{
    return _menu(condition, 0, action, args...);
}

int main() {
    menu(1, print0, print1, print2, print3); // вывод будет 1
    menu('2' - 48, print0, print1, print2, print3); // вывод будет 2, так как в
    // ascii символы цифр расположены начиная с 48 позиции (48 символ ascii это '0')
    return 0;
}
```

Еще [пример](http://ideone.com/3EYNIn) на ideone.

---

Как это работает: сначала вызывается `menu` с аргументами, описанными выше.
Далее она вызывает `_menu`, передавая ей свои аргументы + устанавливая счетчик в 0. Функция `_menu` условно "откусывает" одну функцию `action` от всех остальных, оставляя остальные в `args`, потом смотрит, совпадает ли счетчик с условием, и, если да, выполняет `action` и завершается, возвращая `true`. Если условие не равно счетчику, то она увеличивает его и рекурсивно вызывает себя, передавая условие, увеличенный счетчик и оставшиеся функции. Если функция осталась одна, то вызывается обычная, а не шаблонная версия функции, и она возвращает `false`, если условие и счетчик не равны.

Comment: Спасибо, будем разбираться

Comment: @lisovskey добавил описание, как оно работает, надеюсь станет понятнее)

Answer (score 1):

Можно примерно вот таким подходом ([пример на ideone](http://ideone.com/QGPLzW)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef void (*FuncType)();
typedef std::vector<FuncType> SwitchType;

void FuncOne() {
  std::cout << "One" << std::endl;    
}

void FuncTwo() {
  std::cout << "Two" << std::endl;    
}

int main() {
  SwitchType Switch;
  Switch.push_back(FuncOne);  
  Switch.push_back(FuncTwo);  
  Switch.push_back(FuncOne);
  for(const auto i: {0,1,2}) Switch[i]();  
  return 0;    
}
```

Вывод:

```
One
Two
One
```

Основная идея - заменить конструкцию `switch` на вектор указателей на функции. Приведенный выше пример конечно незаконченный (`default` секции нет), индексы строго по порядку. Но это все легко решается. К примеру, вектор можно заменить `std::map`, а секцию `default` обработать пробросом исключения.